# Build a spreadsheet from a list of tuples of (row, column, value) using 2D array. no numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Hi I took a class of python as one of the "side" course> I am new to python and only learn python via internet/free course so I have no idea or how to.
In the array-based spreadsheet implementation, we use the Python list (a data structure) as the
basis to implement common operations for a spreadsheet. A spreadsheet is a 2D structure of cells,
and each cell can hold different data types, e.g., general, number etc. For this assignment, we will
concentrate on cells only holding floats. Hence to implement a spreadsheet, we will need to implement
a 2D array.
The 2D array is indexed by the tuple (row,column) in the spreadsheet. An example is if we use
numbers to index rows, and letters for columns, we might have (10,8) to specify the cell of the 11th
row, 9th column (we assume indices start at 0).

```
arr = [[0, 0, 9], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2.0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 7], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 6]]
w, h = 0, 0
curRow = [];
ssheet = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
for i in range(0, 3):
    print("loop i ", i)
    for cell in arr:
        print("loop cell", i, cell)

        if cell[0] == i:
            print(cell)
            print(cell[2], end="<-cell2/ currow->")
            curRow.append(cell[2])
            print(curRow)

ssheet.insert(0, curRow)
print(ssheet, "sheet")
```

This is what I got `[[9, 2, 2.0, 2, 5, 7, 3, 6]] sheet`

This is what I tried to have `[[9, 2, 2.0], [2, 5, 7], [3, 6, None?]]` sheet

Comment: You need another list (let's call it `result`). For each iteration of the outer for-loop set `curRow` to an empty list at the beginning and append the final `curRow` to `result` at the end of the iteration.

Comment: Just as a note on terminology: they're called lists in Python, not arrays. If the course you took called them arrays, it was wrong. (Yes, I know about the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module, that's a very specific data structure for a very specific purpose, and is hardly ever used.)

Comment: @MattDMo Python’s built-in ‘list’ is equivalent to ‘array’ in other languages. This is in the lecture. Thanks for clarify for me. They also called it list.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for your comment. I had thougth about that but dont know how to do it

Comment: Python doesn't have "2D arrays". You seem to mean a *list of lists*

Comment: "Python’s built-in ‘list’ is equivalent to ‘array’ in other languages. " no really. It depends on the language. The problem is that the term "array" is used quite loosly. Hence, why you should just say *list* when you mean a *Python list*. Especially since in the context of Python, "array" *implies* numpy array

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the suggestion of @Michael Butscher to fix your code, another approach, that is simpler in my opinion, is initializing an 2d list with all `None` and then using multi-dimensional indexing to fill it with the appropriate values, here is the approach:

```
arr = [[0, 0, 9], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 2.0], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 7], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 6]]

# Determine the dimensions of the 2D array
max_row = max(arr, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
max_col = max(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]

# Create the 2D array
ssheet = [[None for j in range(max_col + 1)] for i in range(max_row + 1)]

# Fill in the 2D array with values from arr
for cell in arr:
    row, col, val = cell
    ssheet[row][col] = val

# Print the 2D array
for row in ssheet:
    print(row)
```

`max_row` and `max_col` can be calculated in a single iteration over `arr` if higher performance is needed.

Comment: WOW. it looks perfect. So clever how you fill in the cell without needing to traverse in arr. What you did for few minutes took me days and I still need help from here. And what do you mean by less efficent. Is mine code supposed to be less efficent because mine need to iterates over arr more than once.

Comment: @PhiThienNguyen I am not sure actually which code is more efficient between mine and yours, if you are curious you can run a benchmark

Comment: @PhiThienNguyen Programming is hard! When I started it also took me a ton of time for simple stuff. Keep at it and you will improve