# Build a spreadsheet from a list of tuples of (row, column, value) using doubly linked list (linked lists of linked lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, doubly-linked-list

I'm hoping to get a result like in [Build a spreadsheet from a list of tuples of (row, column, value) using 2D array. no numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932806/build-a-spreadsheet-from-a-list-of-tuples-of-row-column-value-using-2d-array), but instead of 2d lists it is a linked list of linked lists.

Currently I have no idea how to build a linked list of linked lists.

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row: int, col: int, val: float):
        # a cell object has the row, column and value
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.val = val

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """
        Convert cell to a string for printing.
        """

        return "(" + str(self.row) + "," + str(self.col) + "," + "{:.2f}".format(self.val) + ")"
```

```
class Node:
    """
    A basic type in linked list
    """

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.m_value = value
        self.m_next = None
        self.m_prev = None

    def get_value(self):
        return self.m_value

    def get_next(self):
        return self.m_next

    def get_prev(self):
        return self.m_prev

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.m_value = value

    def set_next(self, next):
        self.m_next = next

    def set_prev(self, prev):
        self.m_prev = prev
```

```
class LinkedListSpreadsheet(BaseSpreadsheet):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rows = LinkedList()
        self.cols = LinkedList()
        self.length = 0

    def buildSpreadsheet(self, lCells: [Cell]):
        """
        Construct the data structure to store nodes.
        @param lCells: list of cells to be stored
        """
        pass
```

I need help to implement the SpreadSheet by finishing `def buildSpreadsheet(self, lCells: [Cell])` lCell or Cell which has row, column, value.

So
`lCell = [[9, 9, 20] [2, 5, 7] [3, 1, 6] [8, 5, -6.7], [1, 1, 3]]`

The result I'm expecting is a linked list of linked lists that store only the value of Cell in location of row and col.

Like the image at col 1 row 1 the val stored is 3.

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtYU.png)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create all those `None` nodes? The advantage of a linked list is that you only need to create the nodes with data. If you start padding them so data appears at certain indexes, you've lost all benefits of a linked list, and should stick with arrays.

Comment: @trincot can you talk in more details please. I was taught here even in the example that one 1 the lab practices to create node for linked lists so that is what I follow. Im open to new idea because I have no logic to implement now. Like how do you create linked list of linked list ? How do you add value on specific index? and if you manage to create then how do you linked the first list and the second list

Comment: Ah I thought you said about creating node Node. Sorry So can you just add value to the specifix index without None ? And what will be the value at empty nodes ? or is it just empty

Comment: Yes, with a linked list you anyhow don't have a way to jump in one operation to a certain index, so you anyhow have to traverse a list from its head node to the next, ...etc. So there is no benefit in storing nodes with None value in such a list. You could only have in that list the nodes that actually have a value, and from the Cell value you can read at which column it sits, which should then correspond to the index you want to retrieve. If you want to set a value, then search for the same column in the list, and if not found then create a node for it. A similar thing can be done for rows..

Comment: How you implement it depends also on which operations you need to support on the spreadsheet. Adding a cell, deleting a cell, updating a cell's value, displaying the sheet in 2D array fashion, ...etc. A linked list is mostly of benefit when the sheet is very sparse, i.e. there are huge gaps between cells which in array format would require a huge amount of intermediate `None` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some remarks:

- There is no use in creating getters and setters on your Node class, when you allow the caller to set/get any value. In that case just have the caller access the attributes directly.
- If the aim is to create a Node instance for every row/col combination, even if there is no data in that node, then there really is no benefit in using linked lists, and you'll be better of with nested (standard) lists. Using linked lists might become more interesting when you *don't* create nodes for where there is no data. This allows to efficiently represent spreadsheets that are very *sparse*, like when there are only a few values, but sitting in row 825812 and columns 9422 and 16840. So I would suggest to only create nodes for cells with data. You would still store them in the right order.
- There are many other choices to make about the data structure, but creating separate lists for columns is not a good idea.
- I would suggest a top-level linked list data structure where the instance inherits from `Node`: this will be a sentinel (dummy) node. Each new node in this linked list will be node instance that has as value another linked list (nested). This nested linked list will represent a row, and each node in it represents a cell (its value is a `Cell` instance). Also this nested linked list will be an instance of `Node`, representing a sentinel node.
- You could add a method that will turn the linked list structure into the more common list-of-lists structure (with `None` at unused cells), so you can more easily test the implementation.

This might not be as you hoped it would be, but I just cannot bring myself of creating a linked list that has a node instance for every coordinate that has no data. It just feels bad:

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row: int, col: int, val: float):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.val = val

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Cell({self.row},{self.col},{self.val})"

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = self.prev = None

    def insertAfter(self, value):
        other = Node(value)
        other.next = self.next
        if other.next:
            other.next.prev = other
        self.next = other
        other.prev = self

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Node(value:{self.value})"

class LinkedList(Node):
    def __init__(self, sentinelvalue=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = sentinelvalue

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.next  # Skip dummy node
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def nodes(self):
        node = self  # Include dummy node
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"LinkedList={super().__str__()})"
    

class LinkedListRow(LinkedList):
    def __init__(self, cell):
        super().__init__(Cell(cell.row, -1, -1))
        self.set(cell)  # A row always has at least one cell with data

    def find(self, col):
        return next(node for node in self.nodes() if not node.next or node.next.value.col > col)
    
    def set(self, cell):
        node = self.find(cell.col)
        if node.value.col == cell.col:
            node.value = cell
        else:
            node.insertAfter(cell)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Row={super().__str__()})"
    
    def asList(self):
        lst = []
        for value in self:
            lst.extend([None] * (value.col - len(lst)))
            lst.append(value)
        return lst

class LinkedListSpreadsheet(LinkedList):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(LinkedListRow(Cell(-1, -1, -1)))
        
    def find(self, row):
        return next(rowlist for rowlist in self.nodes() if not rowlist.next or rowlist.next.value.value.row > row)
    
    def set(self, cell):
        node = self.find(cell.row)
        if node.value.value.row == cell.row:
            node.value.set(cell)
        else:
            node.insertAfter(LinkedListRow(cell))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Spreadsheet={super().__str__()})"

    def asList(self):
        matrix = []
        for rowlist in self:
            matrix.extend(([] for _ in range(rowlist.value.row - len(matrix))))
            matrix.append(rowlist.asList())
        # pad the inner lists so they have equal length
        maxcols = max(map(len, matrix))
        for row in matrix:
            row.extend([None] * (maxcols - len(row)))
        return matrix
```

Demo run:

```
sheet = LinkedListSpreadsheet()
sheet.set(Cell(1, 10, 3))
sheet.set(Cell(1, 3, 9))
sheet.set(Cell(1, 2, 18))
sheet.set(Cell(1, 0, -10))
sheet.set(Cell(4, 5, 55))
for row in sheet.asList():
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you I didnt use your code but your words gave me some ideas